# npm install chromedriver not working. Current existing ChromeDriver binary is unavailable

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

chromedriver not installing

[image: chromedriver not installing]

I'm trying to install npm install chromedriver but it says Current existing ChromeDriver binary is unavailable.

system configuration:
windows 10 subsystem,
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

```
npm log file:

1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'install', 'chromedriver' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v14.2.0
4 verbose npm-session 9e106cc8fc3aec03
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chromedriver 654ms (from cache)
8 silly pacote version manifest for chromedriver@80.0.0 fetched in 748ms
9 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 6415ms
10 silly install loadIdealTree
11 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
12 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 8ms
13 silly install loadShrinkwrap
14 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 222ms
15 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
16 silly resolveWithNewModule chromedriver@80.0.0 checking installable status
17 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tcp-port-used 320ms (from cache)
18 silly pacote range manifest for tcp-port-used@^1.0.1 fetched in 323ms
19 silly resolveWithNewModule tcp-port-used@1.0.1 checking installable status
20 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/extract-zip 340ms (from cache)
21 silly pacote range manifest for extract-zip@^1.6.7 fetched in 350ms
22 silly resolveWithNewModule extract-zip@1.7.0 checking installable status
23 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/del 366ms (from cache)
24 silly pacote range manifest for del@^4.1.1 fetched in 377ms
25 silly resolveWithNewModule del@4.1.1 checking installable status
26 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@testim%2fchrome-version 846ms (from cache)
27 silly pacote range manifest for @testim/chrome-version@^1.0.7 fetched in 851ms
28 silly resolveWithNewModule @testim/chrome-version@1.0.7 checking installable status
29 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/p-map 182ms (from cache)
30 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fglob 201ms (from cache)
31 silly pacote range manifest for @types/glob@^7.1.1 fetched in 209ms
32 silly resolveWithNewModule @types/glob@7.1.1 checking installable status
33 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pify 208ms (from cache)
34 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf 211ms (from cache)
35 silly pacote range manifest for p-map@^2.0.0 fetched in 214ms
36 silly resolveWithNewModule p-map@2.1.0 checking installable status
37 silly pacote range manifest for pify@^4.0.1 fetched in 223ms
38 silly resolveWithNewModule pify@4.0.1 checking installable status
39 silly pacote range manifest for rimraf@^2.6.3 fetched in 231ms
40 silly resolveWithNewModule rimraf@2.7.1 checking installable status
41 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-path-in-cwd 388ms (from cache)
42 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-path-cwd 389ms (from cache)
```

Answer (score 2):

network problem?
I also encounter this error, and I didn't do anything and run install again, it successed.